# SolrJ: Field mappings by mixin

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Is it possible with SolrJ to define a bean and provide its field mapping by a mixin class when using `QueryResponse#getBeans(Class)`?

Example: Let E be an entity with a `name` attribute. The schema defines `*_s_de` and `*_s_en` dynamic fields.

Depending on a supplied language identifier I want to map the `name_s_de` or `name_s_en` field value to the `name` attribute of E without changing its implementation to have `@Field("name_s_de")` hardcoded.

Thanks!